# HTML5 Canvas change circle into square

Tags: javascript, html5-canvas

I would like to create a canvas that has a 100x100 pixel blue square on it.
Position the square along the left side of the page, 50 pixels from the top. Using javascript animate this square so that it moves 10 pixels right and 10 pixels down per second. When the box hits or goes over an edge of the window, change the direction for the related axis.

The following canvas return blue circle but I want 100X100px square instead of circle. I tried `rect(50, 50, 50, 50);` but animation stopped working

```
<style type="text/css">
    canvas{
        border-style: inset;
        background-color: lightgray;
        border-radius: 5px;
    }
</style>
</head>
<body style="background-color: gray;" onload="animate()">
    <canvas id="bouncyBall" width="500" height="250">
    </canvas>

    <script type="text/javascript">
        var animation;
        var centerX = 50;
        var centerY = 50;
        var radius = 20;
        var boardX = 500;
        var boardY = 250;
        var ballDx = 2;
        var ballDy = 2;

        function drawBall() {
            var content = document.getElementById("bouncyBall");
            var me = content.getContext("2d");
            me.clearRect(0,0,content.width,content.height);

            centerX = centerX + ballDx;
            centerY = centerY + ballDy;

            me.beginPath();
            me.arc(centerX,centerY,radius,0,Math.PI*2,false);
            me.stroke();
            me.fillStyle = "blue";
            me.fill();;
            me.stroke();

            if (centerY > boardY - radius || centerY - radius < 0) {
                ballDy = -1*ballDy;
            }
            if (centerX > boardX - radius || centerX < radius) {
                ballDx = -1*ballDx;
            }
        }

        function animate() {
            clearInterval(animation);
            setInterval(drawBall, 25);
        }
    </script>
</body>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [rect](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Canvas_API/Tutorial/Drawing_shapes#Path2D_example)

```js
var animation;
        var centerX = 50;
        var centerY = 50;
        var radius = 0;
        var boardX = 500;
        var boardY = 250;
        var ballDx = 2;
        var ballDy = 2;
        var width = 100;
        var height = 100;

        function drawBall() {
            var content = document.getElementById("bouncyBall");
            var me = content.getContext("2d");
            me.clearRect(0,0,content.width,content.height);

            centerX = centerX + ballDx;
            centerY = centerY + ballDy;

            me.beginPath();
            me.rect(centerX,centerY,width,height);
            me.stroke();
            me.fillStyle = "blue";
            me.fill();;
            me.stroke();

            if (centerY > boardY - width || centerY - radius < 0) {
                ballDy = -1*ballDy;
            }
            if (centerX > boardX - height || centerX < radius) {
                ballDx = -1*ballDx;
            }
        }

        function animate() {
            clearInterval(animation);
            setInterval(drawBall, 25);
        }
        
        animate();
```

```css
canvas{
        border-style: inset;
        background-color: lightgray;
        border-radius: 5px;
    }
```

```html
<canvas id="bouncyBall" width="500" height="250">
    </canvas>
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm using `me.rect(centerX-radius, centerY-radius,2*radius,2*radius)`. This way the center of your rect is in the same spot as the center of the circle.The width of your rect should br 2*radius.

```js
        //var animation;
        var centerX = 50;
        var centerY = 50;
        var radius = 20;
        var boardX = 500;
        var boardY = 250;
        var ballDx = 2;
        var ballDy = 2;

        function drawBall() {
            var content = document.getElementById("bouncyBall");
            var me = content.getContext("2d");
            me.clearRect(0,0,content.width,content.height);

            centerX = centerX + ballDx;
            centerY = centerY + ballDy;
            /*
            me.beginPath();
            me.arc(centerX,centerY,radius,0,Math.PI*2,false);
            //me.stroke();
            me.fillStyle = "blue";
            me.fill();
            me.stroke();*/
          
            me.beginPath();
            me.rect(centerX-radius, centerY-radius,2*radius,2*radius);
            me.fillStyle = "blue";
            me.fill();
            me.stroke();

            if (centerY > boardY - radius || centerY - radius < 0) {
                ballDy = -1*ballDy;
            }
            if (centerX > boardX - radius || centerX < radius) {
                ballDx = -1*ballDx;
            }
        }



        function animate() {
            clearInterval(animate);
            setInterval(drawBall, 25);
        }




animate()
```

```css
 canvas{
        border-style: inset;
        background-color: lightgray;
        border-radius: 5px;
    }
```

```html
<canvas id="bouncyBall" width="500" height="250">
    </canvas>
```